# How do I know my Samsung S8+ Model SM-G955FD is Exynos and Snapdragon?

Tags: twrp

I want to root my S8+. I found two type of TWRP recovery file Exynos and Snapdragon for my SM-G955FD.I wanted to know which one is suitable for my mobile?

Comment: you can use a app (no root required) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.andr7e.deviceinfohw
UNIVERSAL8895=Exynos(dream2lte)
MSM8998=Snapdragon(dream2qlte)

Answer (score 1):

The model number unambiguously determines the device's core configuration - if it says G955F(D) everywhere on the device (especially in Download Mode, which AFAIK can't be faked), then you can be sure that it's an Exynos variant.

Boot into Download Mode with the key combo VOL- + BIXBY + POWER, and you'll be greeted with a screen like below, where the model number will be shown after "PRODUCT NAME".

[image]

EDIT: For a more detailed breakdown of all S8+ models (full specs), check out this list from PhoneDB: [Samsung Dream 2](http://phonedb.net/index.php?m=device&s=query&d=detailed_specs&codename=Samsung_Dream_2#result) ("Dream 2" is the development codename of S8+)

Comment: Why the downvote? Haven't I given an explicit answer based on what OP offered?

Comment: "unambiguously" is misleading

Comment: @alecxs Uhh... How so? I know that the ending letter doesn't concretely define the region/country, but at least the SoC and even supported bands are tied to it.

Comment: afaik the D just stands for dual-sim, but there is no official list for the letters. do you have a source for it? besides it might not be unique identifier (can far remember about GT-I9301i comes with sony or samsung camera)

Comment: @alecxs F = international, not necessarily Exynos for all devices but Exynos in S8's case. By "unambiguously" I mean where we know for sure that there are both Exynos and Snapdragon variants at play (which OP made clear), in which case F is always Exynos.

Comment: @alecxs And I did limit the discussion to "core configuration"...

Comment: @alecxs As for the source of my knowledge on the trailing letters, AFAIK Samsung doesn't offer an official explanation on this (I figure they'd rather you ignore the difference and fall into carriers' trap). If you think unofficial ones around the web are acceptable then I'll edit and add one, but then again I've posted answers regarding the trailing letters without citing sources and it never got frown upon, which is why I find it surprising this time.